# Install Windows IoT headless

Tags: software-installation, windows-iot

Is it possible to set up Windows 10 IoT without any displays or keyboard attached to the Raspberry Pi 3? I see that when creating the SD card you can add a WiFi login, which is a start.

Do I absolutely need to connect a display to finish the installation or can I manage everything from the web interface / dashboard?

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know the first time boot-up is fully automated then reboots and you have access to the following remote management resources.

1. WebGUI accessible on `a.b.c.d:8080` by any moderns web browser. This is just a remote control panel type GUI. You an start stop processes, connect to WiFi and set other options, like Remote Display.
2. Remote Display (not Remote Desktop) needs to be enabled (as above) on the Pi and then you can use the Remote Display client to connect on any computer and OS. This works like a monitor over IP - So you see exactly what is on the screen, literately, a remote display.
3. PowerShell via SSH `administrator:p@ssw0rd` - But you need to know your way around PowerShell commands to get anything useful done.

You may have to start with a Wired network connection though as you would have to setup your WiFi via the WebGUI or PowerShell first.

Comment: I see. I will read up on PowerShell then. What is the setting for WiFi in the SD card creation though - what's it for if I have to set up WiFi on the device itself after installation?

Comment: https://www.hackster.io/windowsiot/powershell-to-connect-to-a-machine-running-windows-10-16a479  - Some nice info about PS. I am not sure what you mean by your WiFi question? You can setup WiFi via PowerShell too but its easier using WebGUI